# How to use if condition and is.null with a list of vector in R

Tags: r

I have a list of vector and would like to make some conditions based on these vectors. All my conditions work good unless this condition

```
if (is.null(w[[i]]))
```

It returns this error:

> Myfu(w=NULL,mat)
>   Error in w[[i]] : 
>     attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex

```
w <- list(c(0.8,0.2),c(0.5,0.4))

mat1 <- c(0, 1, 3, 4, 4,
            0, 0, 3, 4, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 4, 1,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 3,
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
mat1 <- matrix(mat1, 5, 5)

# define R-vine pair-copula parameter matrix
mat2 <- c(0, 0.2, 0.9, 1.5, 3.9,
         0, 0, 1.1, 1.6, 0.9,
         0, 0, 0, 1.9, 0.5,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 4.8,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
mat2 <- matrix(mat2, 5, 5)

mat <- list(mat1,mat2)


Myfu <- function(w,mat){
    m <- length(w)
    for(i in 1:m){
if (is.null(w[[i]]))
    w[[i]] <- rep.int(1/m, m)

if (sum(w[[i]]) > 1)
    stop("w must add to one")
if(any(w[[i]] < 0))
    stop("w must be positive")
}
return(w)

}
```

Any help, please?

Comment: You have `w` as a `list`.  Both the list elements are not NULL.  So, if you pass the function `Myfu(w, mat)#
[[1]]
[1] 0.8 0.2

[[2]]
[1] 0.5 0.4`  For experimental purpose, the `Myfu(w= list(NULL), mat)
#[[1]]
[1] 1`

Comment: I set my `w <- list(NULL,NULL)` and I still got this error

Comment: The guilty is `for (i in 1:m)`, when `length(w)` is zero. Use `for(i in seq_along(w))`.

Comment: I am not getting any error with that `w <- list(NULL,NULL);
Myfu(w, mat) 
[[1]]
[1] 0.5 0.5

[[2]]
[1] 0.5 0.5`

Comment: I'm getting the same as @akrun. But do make the change I've posted, it is **always** good practice to use either `seq_along` or `seq_len`.

Comment: It works now. Thanks for all of you.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I do not understand their benefits.

Comment: If `m == 0` then `1:m` is the vector `1:0` and you will try to index a vector with `0` at the second iteration, illegal. With `seq_along(NULL)` the loop is never executed and there is no error. Try to see what `seq_along(NULL)` returns.

Comment: @RuiBarradas amazing. Thank you so much.